# How to order events close to today's date

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores events with the php timestamp format. I would like to get the next 10 events.

`SELECT * FROM myTBL WHERE event_time >= TODAY ORDER BY (The closest time to today)`

Any help on writing this query would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM myTBL WHERE event_time >= TODAY ORDER BY event_time ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but what would "TODAY" be to match the timestamp in the column. CURTIME() ?